# Python test assertContains – AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'streaming'

Tags: python, testing

I am testing a html response object with [assertContains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/test/testcases/#SimpleTestCase.assertContains):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.test import TestCase

from .signals import check_mailchimp_campaign
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from wagchimp.models import WagchimpCampaign, MailchimpSetting

class WagchimpCampaignTestCase(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['sites.json']

    def setUp(self):
        MailchimpSetting.objects.create(api_key='9b69a8e3a3116aea899-us1',
            note='names', site_id='2')
        a = WagchimpCampaign.objects.create(name="jons",
            campaign_id="1", subject_line="New email",
            top_line="Hi")
        apikey = MailchimpSetting.objects.get().api_key
        a.rss_feed.add = 'skeletal'

    def test_mailchimp_api_response_on_signal_handler(self):
        r = check_mailchimp_campaign(post_save)
        status_code = str(r.status_code)
        self.assertEquals(status_code, '200')
```

which tests connectivity to the Mailchimp API in the following signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import requests

from .models import RSSFeed, WagchimpCampaign, MailchimpSetting

@receiver(post_save, sender=WagchimpCampaign)
def check_mailchimp_campaign(sender, **kwargs):
    apikey = MailchimpSetting.objects.get().api_key
    r = requests.get('https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/',
        auth=('user', apikey))
    return r
```

and am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/technical/code/pb/tests.py", line 46, in test_mailchimp_api_response_on_signal_handler
    self.assertContains(r, "", status_code=200)
  File "/Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest6-PGdhJpMT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 385, in assertContains
    response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
  File "/Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest6-PGdhJpMT/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 360, in _assert_contains
    if response.streaming:
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'streaming'
```

The response object comes with a 200 status code and seems well-formed. Why should this fail if there is no streaming attribute?

Comment: It is more helpful to post the full stack trace rather than just the error. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: And you probably need to post the rest of the test. You seem to be hinting that `response` is something you've got from querying an external API - which firstly is not what `assertContains` is expecting but secondly is a really bad idea to do in a test.

Comment: Do you use Python or Django Unit tests? Could you please include a [mcve]!

Comment: Django TestCase

Comment: @DanielRoseman The docs simply say that this assertion: "Asserts that a Response instance produced the given status_code and that text appears in the content of the response." It just says a response, not seemingly precluding external API responses. Do you recommend not testing API connectivity in unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mention in the docs about `assertContains` working with Response instances specifically refers to the internal Response class returned from the Django test client, described [further up that page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses).

In any case, as I mentioned, you should absolutely not be querying external APIs in your tests. A unit test, by definition, should only exercise the unit of code - everything else is external. What's the use of testing whether an API works? What you should test is that given a specific response from an API, your own code does what it is expected to. You can use mocks for that.